# Android :Programmatically created contact is not syncing with Gmail Account

Tags: android, contacts

I can create a new contact with in My App using:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                rawContactInsertIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "9X-XXXXXXXXX").build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                rawContactInsertIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan")
        .build());
try {
    ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(
            ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It Works fine and I can see contact is been created but when I sync my contacts with my Gmail Account, I can't see that there in Gmail Contacts.

note : If I creates a contact using device's native contact app and sync with Gmail, I can see that contact with in Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some how I figured it out ...

You could use

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google")
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "xxxxx@gmail.com")
        .build());
```

Where, `com.google` is type of account and `xxxxx@gmail.com` is your account id you want to sync with.

Thank you

Comment: If I want to sync contacts under custom account then??
I have used same coding but my added contacts are not showing under my account.. :(

Comment: what do you mean by custom account ?

Comment: Custom account means : if I have installed ma app name XXX, group will b created as XXX in contacts and all the contacts from the server will be added to this group only.

Comment: So you just want to fetch contact information from your own application server and want to add in a group named as your application's name. right?

Comment: please ask a question for this. i can't provide you details here just because the lack of space and it has nothing to do with this thread.

Comment: @TheVOYOU how can I add google contact with it's `googleid`?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I have created new post about sync with other apps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454841/android-programmatically-updated-contact-is-not-syncing-with-other-apps