# How to programmatically add contact that is synced with google

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

In my application that I'm building I can add contacts to my native contacts list. But the contacts I'm adding are phone-only. How can I programmatically add contact that will be synced with Google account, or even better to ask me if I want the contact to be synced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to sync it with google account. Here's the solution for that:

[Android :Programmatically created contact is not syncing with Gmail Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179380/android-programmatically-created-contact-is-not-syncing-with-gmail-account)